# Datatables with Checkbox for Model & Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, datatable

I'm very exciting to use datatable with checkbox from this example [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570465/datatables-select-all-checkbox) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567821/select-all-checkbox-in-datatables-inverted-operation) for bulk approval that is provided [Gyrocode.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3549014/gyrocode-com).

What I'm facing right now are

1. How to prepare **Model** that suitable when all the checked IDs send to
   **Controller**. I use 'serialize' to send data from view to controller.
2. In this case, my project use stored procedure. Do I have to send all of those bulk IDs by using asynchronous process (await & async)

this my view code

```
    var dataToPost = $('#frm_Approval').serialize();
    alert(dataToPost);

    $.post("Payment_Approval", dataToPost)
        .done(function (data) {

        })
```

Please advice me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i'll do. I'll build a string using all the checked id's separated by a comma (",") and pass that to a controller using Ajax Post. Then in my function for processing the checked id's i'll perform a split, splitting the string and assign it to an array and process each id accordingly.

Comment: yes, by using splitting. keys.ID_Keys.Split(','). Thx's